# How to enter POST data into database?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Sample code:

```
echo $mylinks;
```

Outputted echo:

```
http://www.google1.com|http://www.google2.com
```

I want to insert each of these into a database table.

Here's what I was trying to use:

```
INSERT INTO `backlinks` (`id`, `link`, `apikey`, `date`) VALUES (NULL, '".$mylinks."', '11bebe13ae7fe257d9ddba22a9d1eea3', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

The problem is, it's inserting into the database like this basically:

```
INSERT INTO `backlinks` (`id`, `link`, `apikey`, `date`) VALUES (NULL, 'http://www.google1.com|http://www.google2.com', '11bebe13ae7fe257d9ddba22a9d1eea3', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Whereas I want each URL to be entered into its own row like this:

```
INSERT INTO `backlinks` (`id`, `link`, `apikey`, `date`) VALUES (NULL, 'http://www.google1.com', '11bebe13ae7fe257d9ddba22a9d1eea3', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
INSERT INTO `backlinks` (`id`, `link`, `apikey`, `date`) VALUES (NULL, 'http://www.google2.com', '11bebe13ae7fe257d9ddba22a9d1eea3', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

URLs are separated by a pipe (|) - there's normally more than one URL that's submitted, but sometimes there's only a single URL - in case that makes a difference.

So how do I submit the URLs into my database so each is on a separate row?

Comment: use `explode()` function and it gives you an array. Then just loop through the array `foreach` and then write your insert query.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can convert this string to an array with php explode function and after that insert data like this:

```
$array = explode('|', $mylinks);
foreach($array as $key => $value)
     //Insert $value into table
```

Answer (score 1):

mysql will not split that for you, you need to split it yourself.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `backlinks` (`id`, `link`, `apikey`, `date`) VALUES (NULL,:link, '11bebe13ae7fe257d9ddba22a9d1eea3', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)");


foreach (explode("|", $mylinks) as $link) {
    $stmt->execute(array(":link" => $link))
}
```

Comment: Any way to do it with mysqli instead?

Comment: yeah just use the corresponding `mysqli_prepare` and `mysqli_stmt_execute` instead

Comment: @Edward PDO Is a lot better than `mysqli` for a multitude of reasons. If you have a chance to use PDO, do it.